Does anyone know if this water damage is mold?
I’m pulling up carpet of new house and I’m finding some water damage on the floor. Seems to all be dry, maybe after the next major rain I can see if there’s any moisture to know if it’s an old or current issue.
I have no experience dealing with mold so I’m out of my depth here.
https://imgur.com/a/R7HuXvT

That is classic water damage. You need to find and correct the source of the water. Then do treatment and repairs.
The black areas of the wood is rotted or beginning the process of rot from wood destroying organisms.
Those areas need to be treated. A mixture of 50% bleach and 50% water will do the job to kill the organisms.
The wood can then be repaired. Areas of minor pitting can be filled with Floor patch and leveler The parts rotted through need to be replaced with new wood.

It looks like (iron) rust staining.
It can probably be removed using oxalic acid; but it's purely cosmetic: if you're going to cover it up there's no need to treat it.

It looks like stain not mold.
But you do have a leak and some rot in that corner, that is damaging the drywall that comes from above so take care of that.
